# Pre-requisites for submitting iBeacon iOS app on apple store

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

I have developed an iOS app which has implementation of iBEacon Technology.

The app detects one specific UUID type of beacons and proceeds further.

As we know, every app get tested by apple testers, how this app would be tested having ibeacon hardware interaction by apple?

Also what are the pre-requisites or steps to be followed to submit iBeacon app to apple store ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions on app-store approval are pretty much off-topic, but I would suggest that you put the UUID details of your beacon into the reviewer notes and they can configure another iOS device as that beacon if the require.  Personally, I have had an app approved which required a specific BLE peripheral for some functionality - Apple did not ask for details on the device or for access - in my case, however it was supplementary functions.  If your app is non-functional without the beacon then you will definitely need to supply the details

Comment: Hi Thank you for reply. But how apple testers, test the various functionality with beacon which are in lined with Content Management system(CMS). Means in my app when beacon is detected, it calls an CMS URL based on its type to fetch further details. Also, are there any different steps or points to follow, while submitting an app specifically for app with Beacon Detection ? Kindly let me know. Your guidance is much appreciated. Thank You !!!

Comment: A beacon definition is just a UUID, major and minor.  I would suggest that you supply these details to Apple that matches up with some beacon in your CMS so that they can test

Answer (score 3):

Like always with the AppStore, review requirements for beacon-based Applications vary depending on the luck of the draw of what reviewer you get.

A few tips:

1. Always submit a video of your app interacting with beacons.
2. Include beacon identifiers in the review notes as @Paulw11 suggests, and describe what action each beacon will cause when detected by your app.  Don't expect that reviewers will actually test this, so make the video comprehensive.
3. Unless you know what you are doing, generally do not specify location background modes in your .plist, otherwise you have higher risk of rejection.

Comment: Thank you Paulw11 and davidgyoung.

Comment: @user2599405 if the answer helpt you might want to select it as the answer.